# How do I evaluate a K-Means unsupervised anomaly detection approach?

Tags: model-evaluation, k-means, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection

how do I evaluate K-means clustering anomaly detection method as there is no labelled data of anomaly class. To find the cluster (K), I have used the silhouette score from Scikit learn library. Scikit learn K-means were used too.

Comment: Is the goal to compare models or hyperparameters? What kind of evaluation are you looking to do?

Comment: im trying to apply in into physical staff access pattern.